# How to make a show case something like a marquee from bottom to top

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Click on [this link](http://www.viveks.com/), you will be redirected to a shopping site.

On the right side, there is an animated block called TOP SELLER.

What kind of plugin is that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a carousel. Just google 'jQuery carousel plugins' and that should get you started.

Comment: karim , other then spy, carsoul,,,

plz refer